# Euler #4 in Python

Tags: python, continue

> A palindromic number reads the same both ways. The largest palindrome made from the product of two 2-digit numbers is 9009 = 91 × 99.
> Find the largest palindrome made from the product of two 3-digit numbers.
>
> http://projecteuler.net/problem=4

Below is my solution to this problem. It works, but I noticed another solution that used

```
if x*y < max_seen: continue
```

like this:

```
def biggest():
    big_x, big_y, max_seen = 0, 0, 0
    for x in xrange(999,99,-1):
        for y in xrange(x, 99,-1): 
            if x*y < max_seen: continue
            if is_palindrome(x*y):
                big_x, big_y, max_seen = x,y, x*y
```

What I don't get is how that line works. The first time through `max_seen = 0` and the first `x*y` is `999*999` which is greater than 0. So that condition isn't met and the next line is run. Makes sense. Eventually, however, `max_seen` will be larger than `x*y` so why does it `continue` here?

It seems this line isn't even needed because if the condition is or isn't met the program will continue anyway. I suspect I'm not understanding how `continue` works in Python.

This is my approach:

```
def find_biggest():
    big_x, big_y, new_pal, max_seen = 0, 0, 0, 0
    for x in range(999, 100, -1):
        for y in range(x, 100, -1):
            if is_palindrome(x*y) == True:
                new_pal = x*y
                if new_pal > max_seen:
                    big_x, big_y, max_seen = x, y, new_pal
```

From an efficiency standpoint the program should exit as soon as all new `x*y` are `< max_seen`, but `999*100` is less than `998*900` (meaning it couldn't stop yet as it still needs to check `998*y`, `997*y`, etc.) so how would you code that?

Comment: Not sure if I should start a new question or not, but just wondering why the is_pal1 test is slower than is_pal2 which seems to do more stuff. `def is_pal1(n):
    if str(n) == str(n)[::-1]:
        return True
def is_pal2(n):
    s0 = str(n)
    s1 = s0[::-1]
    if s0 == s1:
        return True`. Hmmm, that doesn't print out well. Sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect the reason that the code checks for `x*y < max_seen` first is that it is an easier test than `is_palindrome`. If you expect many of your potential `x` and `y` values to be no good, it makes sense to do the easiest tests first so that you only need to run the complicated tests a few times.

That said, if `x*y < max_seen` is true, there won't be any successful tests for the current `x` value. An optimization could be to replace `continue` (which goes on to the next `y` value) with `break` (which ends the inner loop and so goes on to the next `x` value).

You could even do something similar for the outer loop, and test if `x * 999 < max_seen`. If so, you'll never find a better result and you can stop looping. Here's how that would look in code:

```
def biggest():
    big_x, big_y, max_seen = 0, 0, 0
    for x in xrange(999,99,-1):
        if x*x < max_seen:
            break # breaks out of outer loop, as no later x value can be better
        for y in xrange(x, 99,-1): 
            if x*y < max_seen:
                break # breaks out of inner loop, no later y value can be better
            if is_palindrome(x*y):
                big_x, big_y, max_seen = x,y, x*y
    return big_x, big_y, max_seen
```

Comment: Thanks. I didn't try your exact code, but just replaced "continue" with "break" in the first example and it was faster. I still don't get the logic here. When x=999 and y=999, x*y IS NOT < max_seen (which is 0 to start) so it doesn't break but checks is_palindrome. When the first max_seen is found and a future x*y IS < max_seen does it break out of the "if" or the "for" loop and which "for" loop? (referring to the first example in the question). EDIT: never mind, I just read the response again and I think I get it.

Comment: One more question. You have the `if x*999 < max_seen: break` line to eliminate useless palindrome tests, which I understand, but why `999`? There are potential times when `x*999` will be larger but already tested or skipped. Putting `y` there won't work (not yet assigned), but is there a way to ensure it doesn't check combinations already checked? For example, after `995*583` is found (`580085`) there is no need to check any `x`,`y` that is smaller in that outer loop. I tried `x*big_y` but that doesn't return the right answer. Thanks.

Comment: @caadrider: Oh, I guess the outer loop's test should really be `x*x < max_seen`, since the inner loop takes `y` from the latest `x` value down to 99. It's just supposed to testing the first product from the inner loop, to see if it's completely pointless to test more `x` values. So after `993*913=906609` has been found, the outer loop can quit at `x=952` (since `952*952=906304` and so the inner loop's `x*y < max_seen` test will never be failed again). I doubt there's a big speed up from the test in the outer loop, since at that point the inner loop will break on the first iteration each time.

Comment: I've edited my answer to do the `x*x` test (and to fix a typo in the `return` line).

Comment: Yes, `x*x` is a bit faster and should test fewer `x`'s. I wonder if there are situations where that would result in skipping values that should not be skipped (something other than the palindrome problem). Anyway, thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 0):

The two approaches are almost the same although the first approach avoids checking the palindrom if the product is smaller than the biggest palindrom already encountered, therefore more efficient.

```
if x*y < max_seen: continue
if is_palindrome(x*y):
   ...
```

To answer your first question, in the first approach, `max_seen` will get large only if it belongs to a palindrom, so it will **not** *eventually* get large.

Comment: Thanks. Looks like the `continue` is an efficiency thing that prevent checking all combinations of `x*y` which makes sense. As described below, `break` is even faster. I wonder if there are cases where `continue` vs `break` would result in different outcomes.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an efficient general solution (~5x faster than others):

```
def pgen(factor):
    ''' Generates stream of palindromes smaller than factor**2 
    starting with largest possible palindrome '''
    pmax = str(factor**2)
    half_palindrome = int(pmax[0:len(pmax)/2]) - 1
    for x in xrange(half_palindrome, 0, -1):
        yield int(str(x) + str(x)[::-1])

def biggest(factor):
    ''' Returns largest palindrome and factors '''
    for palindrome in pgen(factor):
        for f1 in xrange(factor/11*11, factor/10, -11):
            f2 = palindrome/f1
            if f2 > factor:
                break
            if f2*f1 == palindrome:
                return palindrome, f1, f2

>>> biggest(99)
(9009, 99, 91)
>>> biggest(999)
(906609, 993, 913)
>>> biggest(9999)
(99000099, 9999, 9901)
>>> biggest(99999)
(9966006699L, 99979, 99681L)
>>> biggest(9999999)
(99956644665999L, 9998017, 9997647L)
>>> biggest(99999999)
(9999000000009999L, 99999999, 99990001L)
>>> biggest(999999999)
(999900665566009999L, 999920317, 999980347L)
```

Comment: Hmmm, can't say I fully understand that, but I like the ability to check multiple lengths. It is slightly slower (`0.0259` sec) than the solution above using `break` (`0.0129` sec) but faster than `continue` (`0.0527` sec).

Comment: The key difference is the use of the palindrome generator. biggest() starts by factoring the largest possible palindrome first, then the second largest, etc. until it finds one that factors.

Comment: Nice. I still like the more general, flexible nature of this one (though still not sure I totally follow). I added a `break` redundancy check for both x and y, as suggested by Blckknght, and now and it's even faster (`0.00702` seconds).

Comment: My palindrome code looks like this: `def is_pal(s): return s == s[::-1]`. I've actually tried 3 but this one is fastest. I posted others in a comment to the original question. Yes, it's the `pgen` stuff I'm not familiar with. Thanks for the tip. I'll explore.

Comment: I found a way of breaking much sooner and updated the above. It now appears to be many times faster than the others.

Comment: Nice. Guess I need to learn about generators now. How long does yours take for a 7 digit number (`9999999`)? Mine took `929` seconds. Ouch.

Comment: A 7 digit number (9999999) takes 6 seconds. (99956644665999L, 9998017, 9997647L). 8 digits takes about 20 seconds. (9999000000009999L, 99999999, 99990001L)

Comment: Okay, that is A LOT faster.